# What's wrong with my array for Wordpress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, posts

I'm trying to exclude certain posts in Wordpress using an array. I can successfully remove one  of the posts by doing this:

```
<?php if ( $post->ID != '443' ) { ?>
  ...
<?php } ?>
```

I'm trying to create an array of posts that I want to remove and have this:

```
<?php $excluded = array('443', '479', '464', '589', '333', '296', '381', '405', '252', '301', '291', '306', '632', '634', '636', '313', '317', '389', '410', '417', '321');
if ( $post->ID != $exclude ) { ?>
  ...
<?php } ?>
```

I've been trying to teach myself PHP and am struggling with arrays, any help?

Comment: shouldn't your if statement be using the $excluded variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing a number with a number does work, as your first example shows.

But im the second one you compare a number (ID) with an array (a list of numbers).

To check, wether the ID is an element of your "excluded" list, you will have to use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (!in_array($post->ID,$exclude)){
...
}
```

Regards,

STEFAN

Answer (score 0):

you should use `in_array` to test if a value is in an array

ie,

```
if (in_array($post->ID, $exclude)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your if statement is you're checking if the postID != the entire array, not if a value is inside that array which matches the value.

You want to use the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. That would look something like:

```
if ( !in_array($post->ID, $exclude )
```